# Shorter REGEXP for MySQL query

Tags: regex, mysql

I want to do a MySQL query to get the following effect:

```
table_column [varchar]
-----------------------
   1|5|7
      25
   55|12
       5
     3&5
    5|11
```

I want a reliable way to get all the values where 5 is the complete value.

So, for example, if I do a REGEXP query for the number 5 on the upper table I would like to get **all rows except** the ones containing **"25"** and **"55|12"**.

This is the best I've come up with so far:

```
[^[:digit:]]5[^[:digit:]] | [^[:digit:]]5 | 5[^[:digit:]] | ^5$
```

is there a shorter way?

Thanks.

Comment: The "word boundaries" solution did the trick. I don't know why that guy deleted his post. And it's not \b5\b as he said, rather it's [[:<:]]5[[:>:]] but thanks a lot for the idea anyway, it worked.

Comment: That would be me; I had deleted it because I initially forgot that MySQL didn't have `\b`, and I didn't remember whether or not it did have a word boundary capability. I've undeleted it and updated it with the proper marks. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using word boundaries:

```
[[:<:]]5[[:>:]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
^.*[^[:digit:]]*5[^[:digit:]]*.*$
```

Comment: Won't work. That expression matches `55`, for instance (keep in mind that the `*` operator can match 0 of an item as well...).